# Assigning Fetched value from database to <select> using PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, database, select

I am fetching data from database using this query for an update form

```php
$vehicleQuery = "SELECT * FROM vehicle_purchased vp where vp.vehicle_id = ".$veh_id;
$vehicle = $db->query($vehicleQuery);
$vehicle_inv = $db->fetch_assoc($vehicle);`
```

Then, I have to bind values,but the technique I am using is not working on select, which is:

```php
<select class="custom-select form-control" 
        id="numberPlateType" name="numberPlateType" 
        value="<?php echo remove_junk($vehicle_inv['number_plate_desc']);?>">
    <option value="1" selected>Both Original</option>
    <option value="2">One Original, One Duplicate</option>
    <option value="3">Both Duplicate</option>
</select>
```

So how can I do this?
( for example, `$vehicle_inv['number_plate_desc'] = 2`  then It should select "One Original, One Duplicate" but it keeps showing default value.

Comment: Where is the question ?

Comment: ^ above mentioned code is not working so what;s the correct way to do that?

Comment: What's not working? what do you mean by "but it keeps showing default value"?

Comment: `select` does not have a `value` attribute in HTML. (Even if you are a student, you should be able to go and _read up_ on stuff like this, instead of just _guessing_, and then wondering why it is not working.)

Answer (score 1):

It keeps showing the default value cause you are asking to do so with "selected " keyword:

```
<option value="1" selected>Both Original</option>
```

Try the following:

```
<option value="1" <?= $vehicle_inv['number_plate_desc'] == 1 ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>Both Original</option>
<option value="2" <?= $vehicle_inv['number_plate_desc'] == 2 ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>One Original, One Duplicate</option>
<option value="3" <?= $vehicle_inv['number_plate_desc'] == 3 ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?> >Both Duplicate</option>
```